# Jenkins job to kill process (Tomcat) over ssh

Tags: shell, jenkins, kill, exit-code

I am using a Jenkins job to run a few simple shell commands (over ssh, via the Jenkins SSH Plugin); the commands are supposed to shut down a running Tomcat server:

```
sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
ps xu | awk '/[t]omcat/{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

The job executes fine and does terminate the Tomcat, but unfortunately it also fails; the full output is:

```
[SSH] executing pre build script:

sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
ps xu | awk '/[t]omcat/{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
[SSH] exit-status: -1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea why the exit code of the command if -1? I have tried several variations without any luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should examine the output of `ps xu`. Since `kill` will kill the processes sequentially, it may be the case that if there are multiple `tomcat` processes yielded by `ps xu`, the other ones will automatically terminate after the first one is terminated. Then `kill` attempts to terminate processes that no longer exist.

Comment: There should be only a single tomcat process running, and the command itself works fine (and exits with 0, not -1) if it is ran by hand. Also, I added the -r option to xargs, to make sure the command doesn't run if it has no input.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Jenkins doesn't like the `no process killed` that the kill command prints of it doesn't run. Try redirecting stdout to /dev/null.

Comment: I changed the command into ps xu | awk '/[t]omcat/{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null; still getting the same: [SSH] exit-status: -1

Answer (score 1):

The questions is a bit old but as I stumbled upon that, here's another suggestion.

```
ps xu | awk '/[t]omcat/{print $2}'
```

returns the running tomcat AND the awk process itself, see here

```
<user>     2370  0.0  0.0  26144  1440 pts/7    R+   10:51   0:00 awk /[t]omcat/{print $2}
```

The awk process instantly ends itself before running xargs on it, so one of the xargs has an exit code unequal 0.

Try running `killall tomcat`

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do `pkill tomcat`?